# Obtener último valor con JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Estoy intentando obtener los valores de una consulta a ElasticSearch. El log me muestra muchos ya que filtro por fecha parseada a milisegundos (ayer,por ejemplo) y deseo obtener el ultima valor json mas actualizado por fecha ya que en algunos momentos me puede mostrar cientos o miles de cambio.

Lo he intentado de todas las maneras posibles pero me sigue pintando toda la lista de consultas que he hecho desde ayer.

Os adjunto mi código y la salida de datos.

```
log.debug("ElasticSearch Connector Reply Query result:" + data.toString());
                 JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(data.toString());
                   JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("hits");
                   JSONArray jsonArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("hits");
                   for (int i = 0, tamaño = jsonArray.length(); i < tamaño; i++)
                   {
                     JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objectInArray);
                     log.debug("%d Numero de elementos en el objeto:\n", elementNames.length);
                     for (String elementName : elementNames)
                     {
                    if(elementName.equals("_source")) {
                       JSONObject value = objectInArray.getJSONObject(elementName);
                       log.debug("nombre=%s, valor=%s\n", elementName, value);
                       String status = value.getString("status");
                       System.out.println();
                       log.debug("Valor elemento Status : "+status);
                       
                         }
                    
                     }
                     System.out.println();
                   }
```

La salida de datos que me muestra la consola:

```
ElasticSearch Connector Reply Query result:{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },"hits" : {
    "total" : 26,
    "max_score" : 4.4721813,
    "hits" : [ {
          "_index" : "connectorreply",
          "_type" : "connectorreply",
          "_id" : "28fea81193c44c3695c8d528cb51aa87",
          "_score" : 4.4721813,
          "_source" : {
            "id" : "28fea81193c44c3695c8d528cb51aa87",
            "lastIndexDateTime" : 1600960665753,
            "name" : "Reply from connector for USER: adtest02",
            "connector" : null,
            "status" : "Error",
            "host" : null,
            "managedSystemId" : "2c9c8e17685c62090168603f45ab0008",
            "connectorId" : null,
            "date" : 1600960665753,
            "lastError" : "La contrase??a no cumple los requisitos de historial, complejidad o longitud del dominio.\r\nEn C:\\Connectors\\ADConnector\\Connector.ps1: 2748 Car??cter: 22\r\n+     $objectToReset | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $newPassword -Reset\r\n+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\nCategoryInfo: InvalidData: (CN=adtest02,OU=...labsanda,DC=com:ADUser) [Set-ADAccountPassword], ADPasswordComplexityException\r\nFullyQualifiedErrorId: ActiveDirectoryServer:1325,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountPassword",
            "applicationId" : "1352@10.4.7.211",
            "targetIdentity" : "adtest02",
            "targetIdentityType" : "USER",
            "operation" : "RESET_PASSWORD"
          }
        }, {
          "_index" : "connectorreply",
          "_type" : "connectorreply",
          "_id" : "3dd7fe158e55458e8bfbcc0c300f4850",
          "_score" : 4.4721813,
          "_source" : {
            "id" : "3dd7fe158e55458e8bfbcc0c300f4850",
            "lastIndexDateTime" : 1600961062275,
            "name" : "Reply from connector for USER: adtest02",
            "connector" : null,
            "status" : "Error",
            "host" : null,
            "managedSystemId" : "2c9c8e17685c62090168603f45ab0008",
            "connectorId" : null,
            "date" : 1600961062275,
            "lastError" : "La contrase??a no cumple los requisitos de historial, complejidad o longitud del dominio.\r\nEn C:\\Connectors\\ADConnector\\Connector.ps1: 2748 Car??cter: 22\r\n+     $objectToReset | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $newPassword -Reset\r\n+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\nCategoryInfo: InvalidData: (CN=adtest02,OU=...labsanda,DC=com:ADUser) [Set-ADAccountPassword], ADPasswordComplexityException\r\nFullyQualifiedErrorId: ActiveDirectoryServer:1325,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountPassword",
            "applicationId" : "1352@10.4.7.211",
            "targetIdentity" : "adtest02",
            "targetIdentityType" : "USER",
            "operation" : "RESET_PASSWORD"
          }
        } ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Pregunto yo. no sería mejor solo obtener el mas nuevo en vez de todos? Es decir si pones size 1 y haces el sort por fecha?

Comment: @nax no entiendo muy bien donde me dices de añadir esos parametros...

Comment: Podrías añadir la query que haces a ES? Pero es básicamente añadir `"size": 1, "sort": [ { "campo_con_fecha" : {"order" : "asc"}}` a la query, eso te dará 1 solo resultado y será el mas nuevo

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-from-size.html#:~:text=The%20size%20parameter%20allows%20you,and%20size%20defaults%20to%2010%20.&text=Note%20that%20from%20%2B%20size%20can%20not%20be%20more%20than%20the%20index.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html

Comment: @nax la query es esta: `{\"size\": 1, \"from\": fromValue, \"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"date\":{\"gt\": ?}}},{\"match\":{\"operation\":\"RESET_PASSWORD\"}},{\"match\":{\"managedSystemId\":\"2c9c8e17685c62090168603f45ab0008\"}},{\"match\":{\"targetIdentity\":\"adtest02\"}}]}}}" `La verdad que estoy probando si esta bien formado en la consola de ES y no soy capaz de incluirle bien esto que me dices sin que se queje,si me puedes echar un cable. he puesto a fuego el size como 1

Comment: Tu json me dice que es inválido. per después de algunos fixes: https://pastebin.com/LaaD5JD1

Como siempre, si ya estás en java mi recomendación es usar el cliente oficial en vez de pasar strings. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.9/java-rest-high-search.html

Comment: @nax me funcionó perfectamente, te agradezco la documentación adjuntada en el comentario. muchas gracias